# Clone vagrant virtual machine to another Windows user

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, vagrant

I have successfully install and run virtual machine centos/7 on vagrant with virtualbox. I have download much file and configured a lot thing inside that virtual machine.

I just need to clone that virtual machine, so other users can access it. Without dependencies with mine. I mean, if I delete my vm, another user can still access the cloned vm.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, we can refer the following article.

[How To Clone Vagrant Virtual Machines](http://alezzandro.com/how-to-clone-vagrant-virtual-machines/)

We can choose two types of cloning: “Full” and “Linked”. The Full clone will have its own disk, the Linked clone will have a disk based on the original and increased for differences (it reduces disk size!).

We can choose “Full” clone according to your description.